# How to not exit on failed download?

Tags: perl, mechanize

How do I download a file with `WWW::Mechanize` without exiting on failed downloads?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get("http://google.com/test", ':content_file' => "tmp");

print "done";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `autocheck => 0` in the constructor :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(
    # perldoc WWW::Mechanize | less +/autocheck
    autocheck => 0
);

$mech->get("http://google.com/test", ':content_file' => "tmp");

# Now, need to check errors manually :
# test on the HTTP return code see :
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
my $retcode = $mech->status();
if ($retcode >= 400) {
    warn("error getting url, HTTP code: [$retcode]\n");
}

print "done\n";
```

Comment: Sure =) `if ($mech->status() >= 400) { warn("error getting url\n"; }`

Comment: Just wanted to point that out. I reached the vote limit so you get my +1 later ;)

Answer (score 4):

use [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try%3a%3aTiny)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Try::Tiny;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

try {
    $mech->get("http://google.com/test", ':content_file' => "tmp");
}
catch {
    print "failed: $_";
}; # <-- do not forget the semicolon

print "done";
```

Leave out the `catch` block if you just want to silence errors.

Answer (score 1):

does it dies on failed downloads? if so, try wrapping that call to 'get' with `eval`..

Comment: It gives `Error GETing http://www.google.com/test: Not Found at ./t.pl line 8`. I have this post where he uses `eval` but I can't figure out how it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499119/problem-getting-mechanize-to-return-value-or-even-an-error-message-argh